# How can I map a Firestore document to a struct?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Model that looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
struct Address {

    //    let dateCreated: Date
    let street: String?
    let city: String?
    let state: String?
    let postalCode: String?
    let country: String?
    let ISOCountryCode: String?
    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var active: Bool?

    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        self.street = dictionary["street"] as? String
        self.city = dictionary["city"] as? String
        self.state = dictionary["state"] as? String
        self.postalCode = dictionary["postalCode"] as? String
        self.country = dictionary["country"] as? String
        self.ISOCountryCode = dictionary["ISOCountryCode"] as? String
        self.coordinates = dictionary["coordinates"] as? CLLocationCoordinate2D
        self.active = dictionary["active"] as? Bool
    }
}
```

I've got a query to documents in Firebase Firestore. I want to map each document to the type of Object it should be; in this case an Address.

For example, i `getDocuments` and then I start looping through each document in the snapshot.documents. My code (that isn't working) to map the document to a type of object looks like this:

```
let closure: (Dictionary<String, Any>) -> String?
closure = { dictionary in
    return Address(dictionary: dictionary)
}
var addresses = [Address]()

addresses = document.data().flatMap(closure)
```

The errors I'm receiving are:

`Cannot assign value of type '([String : Any]) -> Address?' to type '(Dictionary<String, Any>) -> String?'`

`Cannot convert value of type '(Dictionary<String, Any>) -> String?' to expected argument type '((key: String, value: Any)) -> String?'`

I'm sure it's something simple, I'm just not sure what I can do to fix it. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
func getAddresses(at path: String, completion: @escaping (([Address]) -> ())) {
    let data = Firestore.firestore().collection(path)
    data.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        let dictionaries = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({$0.data()}) ?? []
        let addresses = dictionaries.compactMap({Address($0)})
        completion(addresses)
    }
}
```

Also, `flatMap` is deprecated now, in favor of `compactMap` for when the closure returns an optional value

Comment: Hi, how can you also save the documentID in the dictionaries ? Thanks