# Convert firestore document into a struct

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that gets documents from a Firestore database, already as an array:

```
 func getAllCategories(completion: @escaping ([BusinessCategory]?) -> Void) {
    database
        .collection("categoriess")
        .order(by: "modified", descending: true)
        .addSnapshotListener { [self] querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("no documents \(String(describing: error))")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            let result = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> BusinessCategory? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: BusinessCategory.self)
            }
            completion(result)
        }
}
```

Now I need the result of this function as a struct. The struct should look like this:

```
var categories: [BusinessCategory] = [
    .init(id: "id1", name: "Doctor", image: "https://icon.url"),
    .init(id: "id2", name: "Restaurant", image: "https://icon.url"),
    .init(id: "id4", name: "Citizen Service", image: "https://icon.url"),
    .init(id: "id5", name: "Barber Shop", image: "https://icon.url"),
    .init(id: "id6", name: "Corona-Test", image: "https://icon.url")
]
```

The data is already stored as a [BusinessCategory] in the Firestore database.

How can I do this? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Sorry for the misleading question. I have to display all categories. Unit now, I do it with the array I posted above. But due to the fact that I now get all categories from Firestore, I would like to use the function I posted. But then I need to get my result into an array. To display all categories:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
        cell.setup(category: categories[indexPath.row])
        return cell
```

The Firestore structure looks like this. Every category has a random id, properties are two strings. [image: Firestore category structure]

Comment: Is your question how to end up with a `[BusinessCategory]` instead of `[BusinessCategory]?`? Because it looks like you've already done the rest? Or, are you trying to figure out how to *return`  a `[BusinessCategory]` from your `getAllCategories` (which you cannot do directly, since `addSnapshotListener` is asynchronous)?

Comment: I think I posted wrong answer. Have you managed to resolve the issue? Would be useful, if you can share screenshot of the Firestore document retrieved, so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your help. I specified the question above, thanks a lot!

Comment: @jnpdx more like returning all categories found on the firestore database, so I can display them

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50646511/13171940) similar to what are you looking for?